# C# SQLite for Windows Phone "out of memory" error

Tags: c#, sqlite, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone

I've been using SQLite for Windows Phone (http://wp7sqlite.codeplex.com/) trying to do a SELECT to two tables I've made. When I tried to do that, once I call `cmd.ExecuteReader()` I got an "out of memory" exception.

Here's the code WP7/C# code:

```
SqliteConnection conexion = new SqliteConnection("Version=3,uri=file:Database.db");
SqliteCommand sql = conexion.CreateCommand();
sql.CommandText = "SELECT a, b FROM tableA, tableB where tableA.id=tableB.id";
SqliteDataReader res = sql.ExecuteReader();
```

Once it executes the ExecuteReader, it shows an "out of memory exception". Here's the stack trace:

```
Message=out of memory
StackTrace:
at Community.CsharpSqlite.SQLiteClient.SqliteCommand.GetNextStatement(String pzStart, String& pzTail, Vdbe& pStmt)
at Community.CsharpSqlite.SQLiteClient.SqliteCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, Boolean want_results, Int32& rows_affected)
at Community.CsharpSqlite.SQLiteClient.SqliteCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
at Community.CsharpSqlite.SQLiteClient.SqliteCommand.ExecuteReader()
at Carretera.Selector..ctor()
at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.InternalInvoke(RuntimeConstructorInfo rtci, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object parameters, CultureInfo culture, Boolean isBinderDefault, Assembly caller, Boolean verifyAccess, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.InternalInvoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
at System.Activator.InternalCreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type)
at System.Windows.Navigation.PageResourceContentLoader.BeginLoad_OnUIThread(AsyncCallback userCallback, PageResourceContentLoaderAsyncResult result)
at System.Windows.Navigation.PageResourceContentLoader.<>c__DisplayClass4.<BeginLoad>b__0(Object args)
at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InternalInvoke(RuntimeMethodInfo rtmi, Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object parameters, CultureInfo culture, Boolean isBinderDefault, Assembly caller, Boolean verifyAccess, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InternalInvoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
at System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke(Object obj, Object[] parameters)
at System.Delegate.DynamicInvokeOne(Object[] args)
at System.MulticastDelegate.DynamicInvokeImpl(Object[] args)
at System.Delegate.DynamicInvoke(Object[] args)
at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Dispatch(DispatcherPriority priority)
at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.OnInvoke(Object context)
at System.Windows.Hosting.CallbackCookie.Invoke(Object[] args)
at System.Windows.Hosting.DelegateWrapper.InternalInvoke(Object[] args)
at System.Windows.RuntimeHost.ManagedHost.InvokeDelegate(IntPtr pHandle, Int32 nParamCount, ScriptParam[] pParams, ScriptParam& pResult)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've managed to get it work, finally. To whoever it needs the solution, re-check that the columns did exist in the database and/or the database has been created rightly.

I've seen when I created the database using transactions, that database actually didn't existed. I think the transaction failed and I was querying to a non existent DB. I've used, later the Isolated Storage Explorer Tool to download from the emulator the database I've created and double checked it. Now its working right.

I don't know why SQLite shows an "out of memory" error when actually the problem is the non existent file itself.

Hope this can help to someone with the same problem as me.